# libQt6Core.so.6 import error for Qt6 on Ubuntu 22.04 python3.10

Tags: pyqt6, ubuntu-22.04

Updated to Ubuntu 22.04 yesterday. I cannot use PyQt6 on Ubuntu 22.04 using python3.10.
PyQt6-Qt6 6.3.1  is installed.

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/cc/Documents/informatics/QualCoder-master/qualcoder/__main__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: libQt6Core.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I also tried to find the libQt6Core.so.6 file but could not, using:

```
find / libQt6Core.so.6
```

Comment: How and when did you install PyQt6? How did you update Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu was updated through a system generated update request. I install pyqt6 through sudo pip install pyqt6   p.s. I upgrade pip first.

Comment: But was Pyqt properly updated after upgrading Ubuntu? Did you run `pip install` again after that? Were you using a venv?

Comment: I was not using a venv. But I would guess the same problem would occur. (I'm not at my dev computer right now, I'm at work). PyQt6 was installed as the new pthon3.10 was installed for 22.04. Previously, I was using python3.8 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: using: locate libQt6Core.so.6   /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PyQt6_Qt6-6.3.1-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/PyQt6/Qt6/lib/libQt6Core.so.6

Comment: My drastic solution was to completely reinstall the Ubuntu 22.04 OS. Then it worked.